# WOW addons, Lua, the meaning of T in local _, T =

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

Recently, I'm trying to look through a WOW addon called VenturePlan, which calculates the result of your command table quest.

It's a simple addon with almost pure '.lua' files. They are 'Collector.lua', 'Loader.lua', 'MissionList.lua', 'MissionView.lua', 'VenturePlan.toc', 'vs-spells.lua', 'vs.lua', 'Widgets.lua', 'Libs/Evie.lua'.

[image: addon file structure]

I have a little knowledge of programming, like python and c. But I haven't written addons for WOW. I got stuck at the very beginning of this addon.

Almost every file has a piece of code

```lua
local _, T = ...
local EV = T.Evie
```

To my understanding, those code at the very beginning, are usually some variable declaration, or module import. Here, seems the author passed some value to 'T', but I can't figure out where this happens, and it's not even a callable function, it's in a .lua file.

Also, I could not find the entry point. It seems 'Loader.lua' will be loaded first, but it never return anything interesting.

So, where does the 'T' come from? and what's the structure of it, where it's defined?

The addon is here https://www.townlong-yak.com/addons/venture-plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua chunks in a file are loaded as a function. WoW will call those functions providing two arguments. First argument is the addon's name and the second one is a table shared among all files of your addon.
That way you don't have to use the global environment to share data between your files.

`local _, T = ...` will store those two arguments in two local variables. `_` is usually to name unused variables. luacheck for example won't raise warnings for unused variables named `_`

`print(_, T)` in all those files and you should get the same string and table.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I currently understand your description~

Answer (score 1):

It seems that WoW will open those *.lua files with C `lua_load`/`luaL_dostring`/`luaL_dofile` or Lua `loadstring`/`loadfile`; they convert Lua code into functions. `...` is a list of arguments to a variadic function; and the multiple assignment `local _, T = ...` means that `_` id the first argument passed to the function and `T` is the second.

Return is not really necessary for this kind of executing Lua code. It can send data back by altering the received arguments, since tables are passed by reference; as well as globals.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, I'm wondering, is there a place that defines the content of T? Or they are the same across all the WOW addons? I mean, since WOW client send some value to this addon, how can I know what's T?

Comment: Yes, I suppose, WoW calls these Lua files passing arguments to them, `T` being the second one; so `T` comes to the addon from the outside .

Comment: I think @Piglet gave the correct answer about 'T', this is an empty table as a space for data sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage example of lua result stack.

```lua
function stack_results()
    return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
end

-- skip 1st, then get 2nd result, then skip 2 results and get 5th result
-- calling stack_results function
local _, a, _, _, b = stack_results()

-- result will be 2, 5
print("Result: ", a, b)
```

```
Result:     2   5
```